# Chrome Window Randomly Disables Key Commands and Events

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, d3.js, localhost

I am in the process of developing a data visualization; however, I have run in to a problem that appears (seemingly randomly). When the page is first loaded, sometimes chrome will 'lock up'; The chrome toolbar will disable all command keys (ie copy, paste, select all...) and events will be incorrectly triggered (mouseover events get triggered on click, click events are triggered on double click, etc...)

I have already tried opening and closing the inspector window, searching for a memory leak, and trying to identify any infinite loops in my code.
I'm running a local http server via python 3, accessing the page via google chrome on macOSX, but I'm not sure if any of that may be related.

Edit: I found that clicking on another application other than chrome and then clicking back on chrome fixes the issue; however, I'd ideally want our user to not have to do that.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your Task Manager to see if Chrome shows a spike in resource usage? How about outputting to the console any data you retrieve so you can see if there's an unusual delay or the type/values of data correlates to the delay?

Comment: Thank you for your response! There was no spike in resource usage (maybe a slight increase, but it was marginal compared to normal variation). There wasn't any noticeable delay for data output.

Comment: As far as the mouse events go, are you using a trackpad or a normal mouse? Have you tried using a different mouse to rule out flaky hardware? Also, can you post minimal code that will reproduce the issue? Without any code to go from, we're just making WAGs, sort of like I am right now.

Comment: Check with another browser, maybe it is caused by a extension on chrome...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I'm unsure of how to produce this in code as it isn't necessarily reproducible, but I'll play around with what I have to try to mimic it. Tried with both mouse and trackpad.